# Async.Start not running expression when called

Tags: .net-core, f#

I have the following expression defined:

```
let startCycle = 
    FDebug.printfn "startCycle"
    let run2 = async {
        FDebug.printfn "Start"
        do! Async.Sleep 1000
        FDebug.printfn "End"
    }
    FDebug.printfn "Here"
    Async.Start (run2, Backend.State.controlBoard.CycleRunningTokenSource.Token)
    (0, "")
```

When the expression 'startCycle' is ran I see only the following output:

```
startCycle
Here
```

For some reason the `run2` function is not being ran when `Async.Start` is called. The system is not doing anything else, so the cpu is not under load. Any ideas on what I'm missing? This is with F# 4.7 and .NET Core 3.

**EDIT**

I made the following change to verify that the Cancellation Token is not cancelled.

```
let startCycle = 
    FDebug.printfn "startCycle"
    let run2 = async {
        FDebug.printfn "Start"
        do! Async.Sleep 1000
        FDebug.printfn "End"
    }
    FDebug.printfn "%A" Backend.State.controlBoard.CycleRunningTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested
    Async.Start (run2, Backend.State.controlBoard.CycleRunningTokenSource.Token)
    (0, "")
```

Output:

```
startCycle
false
```

The process that called `startCycle` is still running after the call to `startCycle` returns. This is part of a WPF application and the user can enter commands, one being `startCycle`, which calls the above expression.

**EDIT 2**

This issue has been resolved after resolving an issue discussed here:
[F# not returning at end of expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382202/f-not-returning-at-end-of-expression)

Comment: `Async.Start` doesn't await the result. Does it work with `Async.RunSynchronously`?

Comment: Is the process ending after you call startCycle?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have above, in general terms, works fine.

For example, this runs perfectly (in terms of showing output, with the delays), in F# Interactive (this includes the output as printed):

```
> let startCycle = 
    printfn "startCycle"
    let run2 = async {
        printfn "Start"
        do! Async.Sleep 1000
        printfn "End"
    }
    printfn "Here"
    Async.Start (run2)
    (0, "");;
startCycle
Here
Start
val startCycle : int * string = (0, "")

> End
```

There are two likely reasons you are seeing this behavior.

1. `Backend.State.controlBoard.CycleRunningTokenSource.Token` is already in a canceled state (or is set to canceled immediately after this value is bound). This will prevent the async workflow from starting.
2. The process exits before the async workflow is started.

Comment: This a part of a WPF application where an event from the UI causes the `startCycle` expression to be called. After `startCycle` returns the UI is still running but is it possible the event is fired on its own thread, which ends after `startCycle` returns?