# F# not returning at end of expression

Tags: .net-core, f#

I have an issue where an F# program is not returning at the end of an expression and ends up executing the next expression below it.

The two expressions as they appear in the file:

```
   let startCycle = 
        printfn "startCycle"
        (0, "")


   let blah = 
        printfn "blah"
        (0, "")
```

And when `startCycle` is called it will print both messages to the console. Stepping through this with the debugger it goes from the first `(0, "")` to `printfn "blah"` and returns when it hits the second `(0,"")`. I've checked the spacing several times, and Visual Studio appears to recognize these as two separate expressions.

Another weird thing is if I call `startCycle` multiple times it only prints on the first time through, every call after that results in nothing printed to the console unless I stop and restart the application. I'm using F# 4.7 with .NET Core 3. What am I missing?

EDIT:
Incase it helps, here is how `startCycle` is called:

```
    let Run (cmdline: string) : (int * string) =
        let cmodel = parseCmd cmdline
        printfn "%A" cmodel
        match cmodel.Command with
        | "sendMsg4" -> Commands.sendMsg4 cmodel.Args
        | "sendMsg7" -> Commands.sendMsg7 cmodel.Args
        | "sendMsg8" -> Commands.sendMsg8 cmodel.Args
        | "sendMsg10" -> Commands.sendMsg10 cmodel.Args
        | "sendMsg16" -> Commands.sendMsg16 cmodel.Args
        | "sendMsg19" -> Commands.sendMsg19 cmodel.Args
        | "sendMsg22" -> Commands.sendMsg22 cmodel.Args
        | "sendMsg29" -> Commands.sendMsg29 cmodel.Args
        | "sendMixMessages1929" -> Commands.sendMixMessages1929
        | "help" | "Help" -> Commands.help cmodel.Args
        | "startCycle" -> Commands.startCycle
        | "stopCycle" -> Commands.stopCycle
        | "cycleStatus" -> Commands.cycleStatus
        | "set" -> Commands.setStateValue cmodel.Args
        | "show" -> Commands.show cmodel.Args
        | "" -> (1, "")
        | _ -> (-1, "Unknown Command")
```

Comment: Can you show the whole source file? If `startCycle` and `blah` are just variables that need to perform side effects to evaluate, then it makes sense that the `printfn` expressions would be triggered.

Comment: All let bindings that aren't functions and are at module level are executed once and only once at the moment any value or function from that module is accessed. Your let bindings fit in this category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startCycle` and `blah` aren't written as functions, they're written as plain values. The `let` keyword in F# is used for both. Don't worry, this is a very common source of confusion for people new to the language.

To create a function that takes no parameters you need to put in a "dummy" parameter of `unit`, which is written as `()`:

```
let startCycle () =
    printfn "startCycle"
    (0, "")
```

This is then called like this: `Commands.startCycle ()`